# How to control two different QGraphicsViews at the same time

Tags: python, pyqt, qgraphicsview

I'm studying [QGraphicsView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html).

```py
self._item = QGraphicsPixmapItem()
self._item.setFlags(QGraphicsPixmapItem.ItemIsFocusable | QGraphicsPixmapItem.ItemIsMovable)

self._scene = QGraphicsScene(self)

self.graphicsView_1.setScene(self._scene)

self._scene.addItem(self._item)

self._item.setPixmap(QPixmap("image_path"))
```

I know that the above sequence is the way to output pictures.

The second line "QGraphicsPixmapItem.ItemIsMovable" This is the mouse option.

I know that outputting an image in this way will move the picture with the mouse.

```py
self._item = QGraphicsPixmapItem()
self._item.setFlags(QGraphicsPixmapItem.ItemIsFocusable | QGraphicsPixmapItem.ItemIsMovable)

self._scene = QGraphicsScene(self)

self.graphicsView_1.setScene(self._scene)
self.graphicsView_2.setScene(self._scene)

self._scene.addItem(self._item)

self._item.setPixmap(QPixmap("image_path"))
```

Then I made another QGraphicsView and applied the same scene as in 1.

[image]

[image]

In this case, if you click and drag the mouse in one QGraphicsView, both will be applied.

However, this has the disadvantage of having to watch the same scene.

[image]

I want to control multiple screens while outputting different pictures to QGraphicsView, but is there a way? Pictures are different, but zoom in, zoom out, pan, I want all QGraphicsviews to have the same control.

**I want to control two different QGraphicsViews at the same time.**

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

from PyQt5.QtCore import QRectF
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsPixmapItem
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsScene

from ui.preview_test import Ui_MainWindow

class mainwindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.graphicsView_1.setCursor(Qt.OpenHandCursor)
        self.graphicsView_1.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        self.graphicsView_2.setCursor(Qt.OpenHandCursor)
        self.graphicsView_2.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        self.graphicsView_1.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.graphicsView_1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        self.graphicsView_2.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.graphicsView_2.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        self.graphicsView_1.setRenderHints(QPainter.Antialiasing | QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing |
                            QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform)
        self.graphicsView_2.setRenderHints(QPainter.Antialiasing | QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing |
                QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform)                   
        self.graphicsView_1.setBackgroundBrush(Qt.black)
        self.graphicsView_2.setBackgroundBrush(Qt.black)

        self._item = QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        self._item.setFlags(QGraphicsPixmapItem.ItemIsFocusable |
                            QGraphicsPixmapItem.ItemIsMovable)
        
        self._scene = QGraphicsScene(self) 
        self.graphicsView_1.setScene(self._scene)
        self.graphicsView_2.setScene(self._scene)
        
        self._scene.addItem(self._item)
        
        self._delta = 0.1 

        self._item.setPixmap(QPixmap("C:/Users/wlxo0/Desktop/960x540 image.png"))
        

        self.show()

    def setBackground(self, color):
        if isinstance(color, QColor):
            self.graphicsView_1.setBackgroundBrush(color)
        elif isinstance(color, (str, Qt.GlobalColor)):
            color = QColor(color)
            if color.isValid():
                self.graphicsView_1.setBackgroundBrush(color)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        self.mouse_x = QMouseEvent.x()
        self.mouse_y = QMouseEvent.y()

        print(f"X : {self.frame_2.x()} <= {self.mouse_x} <= {self.frame_2.x() + self.frame_2.width()-1}, Y : {self.frame_2.y()} <= {self.mouse_y} <= {self.frame_2.y() + self.frame_2.height()-1}")

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
            self.zoomIn()
        else:
            self.zoomOut()

    def zoomIn(self):
        self.zoom(1 + self._delta)

    def zoomOut(self):
        self.zoom(1 - self._delta)

    def zoom(self, factor):
        _factor = self.graphicsView_1.transform().scale(
            factor, factor).mapRect(QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1)).width()
        _factor2 = self.graphicsView_2.transform().scale(
            factor, factor).mapRect(QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1)).width()
        if _factor < 0.07 or _factor > 100:
            return
        if _factor2 < 0.07 or _factor2 > 100:
            return
        
        self.graphicsView_1.scale(factor, factor)
        self.graphicsView_2.scale(factor, factor)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = mainwindow()
    app.exec_()
```

[Original_Code](https://github.com/PyQt5/PyQt/blob/master/QGraphicsView/ImageView.py) I was editing the code I found on github.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.graphicsView_1 = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.centralwidget)
        self.graphicsView_1.setObjectName("graphicsView_1")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.graphicsView_1)
        self.graphicsView_2 = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.centralwidget)
        self.graphicsView_2.setObjectName("graphicsView_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.graphicsView_2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The UI was created using Qt Designer.

Comment: You have to use different `QGraphicsScene` instances for each view. Then manually sync the parts you want to match, like zoom and position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's only a partial answer, as doing what you're trying to achieve requires a much complex implementation.

The first requirement is to use a unique scene for each view, because if you use the same scene you obviously have the same contents.

Then, you can use a QGraphicsObject as a "container" for the pixmap item. Basic QGraphicsItems don't inherit from QObject (a basic requirement for signals), and QGraphicsObject inherit from both QGraphicsItem and QObject.

By intercepting the `ItemPositionHasChanged` change, you can then emit the signal with the new position, and connect the two items in the two scenes with their `setPos`.

```
class PixmapItem(QtWidgets.QGraphicsObject):
    moved = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QPointF)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.pixmapItem = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem(self)
        self.setFlags(
            self.ItemIsFocusable | 
            self.ItemIsMovable | 
            self.ItemSendsGeometryChanges)

    def setPixmap(self, pixmap):
        self.pixmapItem.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.pixmapItem.setPos(-self.pixmapItem.boundingRect().center())

    def boundingRect(self):
        return self.childrenBoundingRect()

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == self.ItemPositionHasChanged:
            self.moved.emit(value)
        return super().itemChange(change, value)

    def paint(self, *args):
        pass


class mainwindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.scene1 = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        self.graphicsView_1.setScene(self.scene1)
        self.item1 = PixmapItem()
        self.scene1.addItem(self.item1)
        self.scene2 = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        self.graphicsView_2.setScene(self.scene2)
        self.item2 = PixmapItem()
        self.scene2.addItem(self.item2)

        self.item1.setPixmap(QPixmap("image1.png"))
        self.item2.setPixmap(QPixmap("image2.png"))

        self.item1.moved.connect(self.item2.setPos)
        self.item2.moved.connect(self.item1.setPos)
```

As said above, this will work, but won't be enough:

- you're implementing the wheel event on the main window, which is problematic: first of all, you'd get a zoom from **any** place (except from widgets that handle wheel events and *accept* them without propagating it to the parent), then, as soon as the image is zoomed, the wheel will also scroll the contents, because hiding the scroll bars doesn't prevent their functionality;
- hiding the scroll bars doesn't prevent the view to scroll the scene whenever required, which can be an issue when the image is bigger than the view and the visible scene rect requires adjustments after moving items;
- the same issue is most important if the images have different sizes, which can result in flickering and other positioning issues everytime the window is resized;

There is no easy solution for this: providing such features requires most certainly to subclass the graphics view in order to provide custom behavior that properly works for each view *and* for the synchronization between them.

Other issues:

- the whole `mapRect` computation is unnecessary: you can get the new factor just by doing `self.graphicsView_1.transform().m11() * factor`, which multiplies the *current* scaling by the given factor. See the [QTransform docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtransform.html#details);
- scaling should always be consistent, and since `scale()` actually is applied to the *current* scale, the result is that you *never* get to the same values; try to add `print(self.graphicsView_1.transform().m11())` at the end of `zoom()` and you'll see that after a few zoom in/out you can never get back to a precise `1.0`;
- use `if not 0.07 <= _factor <= 100:`;